# I can't get the request value from input value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, roles, laravel-permission

**UPDATE: So i just found out that `$request` can only get the `input name` so i had to change the radiobox form so that the `input name` must be different**

So i'm working with roles and permissions in laravel and i'm using spatie package for roles and permission `https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission` but i'm stuck in a radio box form. I'm trying to give the admin the option to change the users role in his dashboard but the value i'm getting from the radiobox is always the last one.

This is the form in my `edit.blade.php`

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="user-role">Role</label>
      <br />
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="admin" @if($user->hasRole('admin')) checked @endif> Admin </input>
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="manager" @if($user->hasRole('manager')) checked @endif> Menager </input>
      </label>
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="user" @if($user->hasRole('user')) checked @endif> User </input>
      </label>
    </div>
```

And this is the function in my `UsersController.php`

```
$request['admin'] ? $user->assignRole('admin') : $user->removeRole('admin');
$request['manager'] ? $user->assignRole('manager') : $user->removeRole('manager');
$request['user'] ? $user->assignRole('user') : $user->removeRole('user');
```

Now the `$request` is getting the `input name` instead of `value` and since the name is the same and i cannot change it because its breaking my form it's getting the last one and it always registered as `user`

Comment: I think you need to change different name values for each input.

Comment: `@if($user->hasRole('admin')) checked @endif` - This doesn't look right. Secondly, isn't the `$request` an object of the class `Request` and not an array?

Comment: @entoniperez i tried that and worked but the problem is that now my radioboxes don't work, now i can select multiple radioboxes and they don't uncheck

Answer (score 0):

Does your controller get the value you are sending from your form

If yes try to access the date with

> $request->get('admin');

Hopefully that will work :)

Comment: I tried this method but now the form send nothing in database :(

Comment: After i checked in more details this method works the same way the method i used it gets the input name instead the input value

Comment: Do you mean that you don't get the controller doesn't get information from the form?